# Using fit for a box through a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, fit

Hi i try to use the command fit to make a box around nodes. But the edge nodes should be only half in the box.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (CE1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}}; 
    \node at (2,0) (PE1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}}; 
    \node at (4,0) (P1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}};  
    \node at (6,0) (P2) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}};  
    \node at (5,-2) (P3) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}}; 
    \node at (8,0) (PE2) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}}; 
    \node at (10,0) (CE2) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{Bilder/Router.png}};    
    \node at (5,-3)(LDP)[scale=0.6, text=black] {directed LDP}; 
    \node (test)[fill=lightgrey , rounded corners, fit= (PE1.mid) (P1) (P2) (P3.south) (PE2.mid)] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

while using PE1.mid the box dosn´t go exactly through the midle of PE1 it has an offset to the left. is there any way to go exactly through the midle of the node?

thx for help

steffen

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  So that others can test your code, it is best to make it in to a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and use a graphic that is available on standard systems such as `example-image-a`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `inner {x|y}sep=0pt`. Adjust it according your needs.
Following code uses `inner xsep=0pt` and the result is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (CE1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-a}}; 
    \node at (2,0) (PE1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-b}}; 
    \node at (4,0) (P1) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-c}};  
    \node at (6,0) (P2) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-a}};  
    \node at (5,-2) (P3) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-b}}; 
    \node at (8,0) (PE2) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-c}}; 
    \node at (10,0) (CE2) {\includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-a}};    
    \node at (5,-3)(LDP)[scale=0.6, text=black] {directed LDP}; 

    \node (test)[draw, rounded corners, 
         fit= (PE1.mid) (P1) (P2) (P3.south) (PE2.mid), 
         inner xsep=0pt] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: thx a lot it works perfect